# Callback events from a javafx scene

Tags: java, events, javafx

I have developed a javafx application which is in fact a learning game. That app contains of several javafx scenes. In one of them which is the main game I want to store the mouse positions and the keyboards events as well. How can I have access to those events from javafx scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use event handler
Using this for mouse_position :

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = event -> { 
/* event.getSceneX() and event.getSceneY() to retrieve positions */
};
main.getScene().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, handler);
main.getScene().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, handler);
```

And this for keyboard :

```
object.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + ke.getText());
    }
});

object.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        System.out.println("Key Released: " + ke.getText());
    }
});
```

Comment: Is object variable my scene variable?

Comment: object had to be a JavaFx node. Yes, it can be the scene variable.